How can I perform better in lecture based quizzes?
I am in a BIO 100 class. The class structure is as follows:

A reading given after class for the next class
A 3 hour lecture
A quiz at the end of the lecture over what went on in class.

I’ve been scoring consistently lower scores with each coming week. At first I got a 10, then a 9, now an 8. What do I need to do to absorb more of the lectures and do better on the quizzes? As far as I am concerned, I cannot have the PowerPoint slides before the day of class.
Update: I was able to get the PowerPoint and I’m using them for studying. Any suggestions on how to best take advantage of this? Quizzes are based on what we talk about in class, both what’s said and what’s on the PowerPoints. Thank you for your helpful answers thus far.

What do you do with the reading in between one class and the next?

That is a teeny amount of variance. I wouldn't consider yourself failing yet when you've scored an average of 90% over three quizzes

I watch a YouTube lecture on the subject so I get the core concepts before going into the textbook material. Then I look for the quiz at the end of the chapter and answer the questions as I go through the textbook and quiz myself throughout the week until the next class.

Azor, I guess when you word it like that, it’s not as bad as I think. I’m trying to get a 4.0 across all my classes for scholarships and this is the only class I’m struggling to maintain a good grade in. Consistent 10s is somewhat unrealistic, but at least 9s and a few 10s I think is a good goal for what I’m capable of. I understand I might be a little too critical.

Turn the lecture into a form of active learning. Just watching and listening is passive and the brain wants more.
Taking notes by writing with pen and paper is a traditional technique. It is likely superior to typing notes as the brain is engaged more. When a "big idea" is presented in the lecture, make a note of that on a note card, one idea per card. These (and the written notes) will be useful later for review.
Some lecturers depend more on the slides than others. Some depend more on what is said and use the slides only for props. Try to figure out which is more important to the lecturer and focus on that, primarily.
If you are making assumptions about not having prior access to the slides, clear that up. A print-out of the slides can be a good place to take notes on what is said about that slide.
Engage your brain. Ask questions if possible about anything you don't understand. Others will probably have the same questions.

Learn actively — don’t just passively read and then passively listen. While you are reading, underline key points (unless it is a library book or one that you want to sell after the course), take notes summarising what you have read, and ask yourself what quiz questions you would ask about this. text if you wanted to test someone else’s understanding of it. Write down those questions and your answers. If possible, do the reading and note-taking well before the lecture so that you have time to review your notes ahead of the lecture itself.
If you have been given a course outline or study guide that indicates what you are expected to learn or be able to do by the end of the course, cross-reference your notes against that.
Keep the notes so that you can come back to them in later study, to help you prepare for your final exams, for instance. Test yourself on the questions you wrote at increasing time intervals later.
During the lectures, take notes — write down key points and perhaps a mind map of how they are related. Ask yourself whether anything covered in the lecture casts a new light on what you read earlier, whether it adds something new or reinforces what you have already learned. Ask yourself whether the way the lecture is presented suggests which parts the lecturer thinks are most important. Ask yourself whether you understand the material well enough to apply it in a different context — ask questions if not!

Improve your active engagements to communicate with the instructor before, during, and after the lectures. Before -- To help you appreciate what could be coming up at the next lecture. During -- To help you cement new information presented at the lecture into your knowledge and/or to translate something in your current knowledge on the topics during the lecture into deeper understandings about those topics. After -- To help you better understand what you apparently may not have mastered to the standards desired by the instructor as per the quiz questions.
